# Dynamically detect XML child

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

How to know if a XML list have a child?
My code below is using hard code stating that I want to run the child of my XML.
But I wouldn't want to write write every children() of it if I have a lot of child.

```
private function dataLevel():void {
        for (var j:Number=0; j<xmlList.length(); j++) {
            createBranch();

            for (var k:int = 0; k<xmlList[j].children().length(); k++) {
                createBranch();
            }

            for (var l:int = 0; l<xmlList[j].children().children().length(); l++) {
                createBranch();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What does `createBranch` do? Doesn't it depend on the name of the child? From the given code, it seems that you just wanna call the `createBranch` as many times as there are children (or grandchildren) - though I'm not sure what `xmlList[j].children().children().length()` is gonna return. If you just wanna get a list of all the children and grandchildren, use the [descendants()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html#descendants()) method.

If you wanna go through the children in the hierarchical order, write a recursive method.

```
function traverseChildren(node:XML):void
{
  //calling createBranch here means one call per each xml children
  createBranch();
  var list:XMLList = node.children();
  for each(var child:XML in list)
  {
    if(child.nodeKind() == "element")
      traverseChildren(child);
    //if you wanna call createBranch for each attribute and text node
    //and comments and processing instructions, call it here instead
  }
}
```

Comment: Well this helps me to figure out the way to solve my question. Thanx!